# IE8 Growing Font Size on MVC 3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Please tell me that I'm crazy, or that my installation of IE8 is broken somehow.

If I create a bare bones form that does almost nothing, IE renders the text in one size before pressing the submit button and then re-renders in a larger size after pressing the submit button. (example image below)

I was able to reproduce this by following these steps.

1) Create a new MVC 3 empty project, not using HTML 5 semantic mark up.

2) Create a new model, 2 strings and a boolean

```
public class Class1
{
    public string string1 { get; set;}
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public bool boolval { get; set; }
}
```

3) Create a controller, don't need to change anything here

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

4) Create a new view on the index action of the above controller.

```
@model testproject.Models.Class1

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <p><input type="submit" value="pressme" /></p>
}
```

5) Edit Global.asax.cs's MapRoute to use your controller

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Default1", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

6) Hit the "Play" (debug) button

When the page loads, everything looks fine. 
HOWEVER, If you hit the submit button, everything grows about one font size

[image: example image]

If you edit out the references to the CSS file and jquery script file in _Layout.cshtml, the strange behavior continues. If you view the rendered source before and after submission, they're identical.  If you view the page from IE8 by directly visiting the URL of your test site and NOT going through the debugger, the issue does NOT appear.  And of course if you view the page from FF or Chrome, there's no issue there either.

Can anyone reproduce this? Am I going crazy? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you watching it in ZOOM 100%?

Comment: Previously I had reset all of IE 8's settings using the Reset button in the advanced tab of internet options. The behavior continued after the reset.  After I saw your post this morning, I tried it again (again with an near-empty MVC 3 project) and noticed that NO zoom level was selected in IE.  I set it to 100% and the problem went away.  For the heck of it, I reset all of IE's settings again, restarted the browser and now the 100% zoom level remains selected, and the problem doesn't reappear. I would have expected the zoom level to be reset to a default with all of the other settings.

Comment: Related http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/reset-internet-explorer-settings-failes-to-reset/025862b7-0fe6-4410-8c85-d3ed7ad35cb6